# UIWebView in TableViewCell height

Tags: ios, uitableview

guys, help, is there a good or any normal way to determine height for uitableviewcells ?
I have cells and uiwebview in, I use `loadHTMLString` for create text with html tags in webview, but it works after delay and i can't calculate height for row in normal way.

Comment: You could show it after it has loaded, make a custom animation with alpha properties so you could reload the table and abjust the height before the user see it.

Comment: Use UIWebView's delegate methods to know when the web view is done loading.. run the height calculation code on that event instead of before loading the web view...

Comment: What kind of html are you specting to render?

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but i need to reloadData to give new height, I'm trying store my heights in NSDictionary so. But some cells have bigger height, not sure why